# How can I run image by tag

Tags: linux, virtualization, docker

```
$ sudo docker images     

REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
ubuntu              13.10               9f676bd305a4        9 days ago          178 MB
ubuntu              saucy               9f676bd305a4        9 days ago          178 MB
ubuntu              raring              eb601b8965b8        9 days ago          166.5 MB
ubuntu              13.04               eb601b8965b8        9 days ago          166.5 MB
ubuntu              12.10               5ac751e8d623        9 days ago          161 MB
ubuntu              quantal             5ac751e8d623        9 days ago          161 MB
ubuntu              10.04               9cc9ea5ea540        9 days ago          180.8 MB
ubuntu              lucid               9cc9ea5ea540        9 days ago          180.8 MB
ubuntu              12.04               9cd978db300e        9 days ago          204.4 MB
ubuntu              latest              9cd978db300e        9 days ago          204.4 MB
ubuntu              precise             9cd978db300e        9 days ago          204.4 MB

$ sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu /bin/bash
```

1. What image I will run when I say 'run ubuntu' ?
2. Can I run image by repository and tag ?  Something like $ sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu 12.04 /bin/bash ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't specify tag, "latest" should be used. You can specify tag or image id as name with colon separator:

```
# tag
sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu:13.04 /bin/bash
# image id
sudo docker run -i -t ubuntu:5ac751e8d623 /bin/bash
```